# Android and Git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am working on my android project. To track the progress I added the project to git. I wanted to test a new feature, so I created a new branch but that didn't create a new copy of my project. How can the original code remain same this way ?
Branches are different but the code is same.

Comment: When you create a branch, it has the same data as the base branch until you commit new code to it.  And you won't see that branch on your local unless you check it out.  It sounds like you just don't understand git.

Comment: Maybe, you didn't commit and push your changes prior creating the branch. Remember that the branch is created based on the last commit in your local repo (is recommended to pull before create a branch so you ensure have the latest changes).

Comment: Yes, I  think that I need to read more about git.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new branch is just a way of starting a new line of history. As you make changes and commit those, you will see that the history of your new branch differs from that of the other branch.

If you plan on using Git frequently, your time would be well invested reading up on the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc). [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/) is a good starting point.